# Shell script - IFS stops after string contains hyphen

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing shell script which will get values of keys from following structure
vars.txt:
`[{"key":"testvar1","value":"abc"},{"key":"testvar2", "value": "abc-de"}]`

First I want to split this string, so I am using
`IFS="," read -d -r -a rows < vars.txt`

but it stops when "value" field contains hyphen:

`echo ${rows[*]}` gives `[{"key":"testvar1" "value":"abc"} {"key":"testvar2" "value": "abc`

How can I fix this issue, so full abc-de will be used?

Comment: BTW, use `declare -p rows` to print your array in unambiguous form. `echo ${array[*]}` doesn't show you the difference between `array=( "first item" "second item" )` and `array=( first "item second" item )`, and it also has nasty side effects like changing the `*` in `array=( hello '*' world )` to a list of files in the current directory.

Comment: That said: The problem is the `-d -r`. `-d` reads the first character of the subsequent argument as character to stop the read at.

Comment: BTW, this isn't an IFS problem. IFS is the _field_ separator, the thing that determines boundaries between array elements in `read -a`; your problem is with the _record_ delimiter, the thing that tells `read` when it's finished reading a record altogether.

Comment: chepner is completely on-point, by the way: the Right Thing is to use a real JSON parser. Shell-native code is extremely fragile; consider, f/e, that the JSON would be just as valid if you had `"value": "abc", "key": "testvar1"` -- or that commas are legal inside JSON strings, so you can have `"value": "abc,def"`; or that backslash-escaped quotes are _also_ valid in JSON strings; etc, etc, etc.

Answer (score 4):

#### Short-Form Explanation

`read -d` requires an argument, the first character of which is the record delimiter -- the character at which the record being read will be considered complete. It's taking `-r` to be that argument, and thus treating the `-` in `-r` as the character to stop reading at.

Just leave the `-d` argument out, unless you know why you're using it.

---

#### Reading input until EOF or a NUL byte

If your intent was to tell `read` to keep going until EOF or a NUL, then pass `''` as the argument following `-d`; thus:

```
IFS=, read -d '' -r -a rows <vars.txt
```

Do note, though, that that will exit with a nonzero status unless `vars.txt` ends with a literal NUL character.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a job for `read`. Use a JSON parser like `jq` to extract the values and `readarray` to populate the shell array.

```
$ readarray -t rows < <(jq -r '.[].value' vars.txt)
$ declare -p rows
declare -a rows=([0]="abc" [1]="abc-de")
```

(Assuming you are using a half-way modern version of `bash`. If you are using a fossil like the version that ships with macOS, install a recent version and prefer using that.)

Comment: Just so. I got caught up in the details of where the OP was getting stuck and didn't look at the big picture of what they were trying to accomplish when it happened.

Comment: I hesitated; I'm *assuming* the input is JSON and not just a JSON-like sample :)